# java.io.FileNotFoundException Permission Denied when saving image

Tags: android

```
private void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap){
    try {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        OutputStream fOut = null;
        File file = new File(path, mWallpaper.getId().toString() + ".jpg");
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut); // saving the Bitmap to a file compressed as a JPEG with 85% compression rate
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();

        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error saving wallpaper. MAL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error saving wallpaper.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I added this to my AndroidManifests:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I am trying to save an image to /storage/emulated/0/.

EDIT

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    permissionCheck);
        }
    }
```

I've added this to onCreate() for my fragment but I still not a request.

Comment: What android version are you using? android 6.0+ works a bit differently from older versions.

Comment: Add your full logcat. Also, if your android version is 6.0+ you have to implement run time permission check. For the code to work, just go to device settings, Applications, you_app, and allow the permissions.

Comment: Have you added the dynamic permission for external storage ? @TQL

Comment: [Here is the doc of runtime permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html), have fun ;)

Answer (score 6):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    }
}
```

Do this if you are using >=api 23. After this add your code. With this code you ask run-time permission from the user.

[Requesting Permissions at Run Time Documentation from official Android site](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Not fully correct but the idea is here. If he add his code after that block, this won't work since the response is asynchronous. PS : you can find the link for the doc in the comment section, I've just added it, this is always good to provide full documentation ;)

Comment: @AxelH you're right. I am going to add this link in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use

```
getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath()
```

rather than

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

If you implement this solution, you do **not** need to add any permission to Manifest because your files are saved in Application directory, not SD Card.

Comment: This is probably a requirement to put it in the external storage ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

            } else {


                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},23
                );
            }
        }
```

try this also you can follow folling link 
http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow

Comment: any reason for down voting ?

Comment: I would guess 1) code-only answer 2) duplicate of answers 3) no source. You probably can improve your answers ;)

Comment: Well, [answer] says _Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better._ so downvote would be acceptable, not great

Comment: Well, now you have some explanation but through a link only, see again the help about links ;) you should extract the information in case this link die (not official documentation link have greater risk to die in the futur)

Comment: The difference between a simple and a good answer is small ;) sorry if I was a bit picky here